# Parse ruby hash within script tag in a index.html.erb file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How would I parse a ruby hash within a `<script>` tag in my `index.html.erb` file?

The controller:

```
@full_calendar_options = { theme: true, header: { left: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay', center: 'title', right: 'prev,next' }, defaultView: 'agendaWeek', buttonIcons: { prev: 'calendar-left-arrow', next: 'calendar-right-arrow' } }
```

In the index.html.erb, this would produce javascript syntax error:

```
<script>
var options =  <%= @full_calendar_options %>;
```

As it would produce:

```
 var options =  {:theme=&gt;true, :header=&gt;{:left=&gt;&quot;month,agendaWeek,agendaDay&quot;, :center=&gt;&quot;title&quot;, :right=&gt;&quot;prev,next&quot;} ...
```

When I wrap the ruby capture with a string, I get no error:

```
var options =  '<%= @full_calendar_options %>';
```

But it produces:

```
var options =  '{:theme=&gt;true, :header=&gt;{:left=&gt;&quot;month,agendaWeek,agendaDay&quot;, :center=&gt;&quot;title&quot;, :right=&gt;&quot;prev,next&quot;}, ...
```

which is an encoded string. It is not JSON so I cannot parse it into an object literal. I am trying to get the object literal in JavaScript. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want this output to JSON, as it looks like you're assigning it to a JavaScript variable. In that case:

```
var options =  <%= @full_calendar_options.to_json %>
```

Comment: Why must I use inspect too? Why wouldn't to_json just work?

Comment: Oops, you're right. `to_json` will work fine without the `inspect`.

Comment: I think html_safe might be required as well: @full_calendar_options.to_json.html_safe

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
var options =  <%= raw @full_calendar_options.to_json %>;
```

Comment: Out of curiosity why does Rails escape the data by default? Isn't it an inconvenience? Who would want data that looks like this? {:theme=&gt;true, :header=&gt;

Comment: This is a good explanation why: http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/ Basically because anything within <%= %> can be unsafe user input, including malicious javascript so it by default escapes it so as not to be malicious.